# Docker rename manifest or merge 2 images into one

Tags: bash, docker, manifest

I have a multiarch docker image called `someserver:5000/my_image:v1`. It is uploaded to some local registry. Image has been made for 2 platforms: `linux/arm64` and `linux/amd64`.

I want to rename this image to `someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1`. If it was a regular image I could just:

```
docker pull someserver:5000/my_image:v1
docker tag someserver:5000/my_image:v1 someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1
docker push someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1
```

But this is a multiarch image done by `docker buildx build --platform <ARCHITECTURES> --pull --push ...`, so while pulling it I get a revision for my architecture.

How can I retag a multiarchitecture image?

Comment: Instead of putting the answer inside the question, it's perfectly fine to add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I was writing this post I've found a solution.

In the beginning I haven't really gotten how multiarch images are created and what are "manifests" in docker. I thought that some multiarch image `someserver:5000/my_image:v1` is like a super-image, but first of all `someserver:5000/my_image:v1` is a tag of repository `my_image` on `someserver:5000` registry. There is some manifest that is tagged like this. And it "points" on one or several real images (Correct me if I'm wrong).

### Docker manifests [solution](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)

#### Solution 1 (If your images are stored locally or online)

1. (*if online - skip this step*) Let's assume that somehow you have 2 images on you local machine - `someserver:5000/my_image:1` and `someserver:5000/my_image:2`. Push them into your registry:

```sh
docker push someserver:5000/my_image:1
docker push someserver:5000/my_image:2
```

2. Unite them under one manifest `someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1`:

```sh
docker manifest create someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1 \
--amend someserver:5000/my_image:1 \
--amend someserver:5000/my_image:2
```

3. Push in into your registry:

```sh
docker manifest push someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1
```

#### Solution 2 (If you want too rename manifest)

Let's say that there is already a manifest with tag `latest` in `my_image` repository on your `someserver:5000/` registry, but you want to "rename" it to `someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1`

1. Get info about the tag

```sh
docker manifest inspect someserver:5000/my_image:latest
```

It will give you something like this:

```json
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 1,
         "digest": "sha256:long_long_hex_number_1",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arch1",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 13735,
         "digest": "sha256:long_long_hex_number_2",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arch2",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

2. Just create a manifest with digests not providing tags:

```sh
docker manifest create someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1 \
--amend someserver:5000/my_image@sha256:long_long_hex_number_1 \
--amend someserver:5000/my_image@sha256:long_long_hex_number_2
```

3. Push in into your registry:

```sh
docker manifest push someserver:5000/my_release_image:v1
```

4. Delete old manifest:

```sh
docker manifest rm someserver:5000/my_image:latest
```